# Is there a way to Replicate the FormData interface from javascript in Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have been trying to post a multipart/form-data using Blazor Web assembly, but have not been successful. I have tried using MultipartFormDataContent() etc, but can't get it to send the data the same way as using javascript. The attached image is the result i am hoping for using blazor, I need to post a file with some additional data to an api endpoint. It accepts form Data.

```
form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="userfile">Upload file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="onPost()" value="Submit!">
</form>
</body>

<script>
    function onPost(){
        let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
        let formData = new FormData(myForm);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "example.com");
        request.send(formData);
    }
    
</script>
```

Here is the html and javascript, so I am basically trying to duplicate the OnPost Function. I just used boilerplate code as an example.

Comment: Does it have to be in FormData format?  The normal route is to use an EditForm and post it as Json.

Comment: Will the file be able to be sent without converting to bytes first?

Comment: I hadn't noticed the file input yet. Just google for what you want:  "upload a file with Blazor".  And all files are bytes.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my project, we needed to send a MultipartFormData (to upload a file via GraphQl).

```
var rawOperations = "upload"; // Short for the example here
HttpContent operations = new StringContent(rawOperations);

string rawMap = "{ \"0\": [\"variables.input.file\"]}";
HttpContent map = new StringContent(rawMap);

using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    formData.Add(operations, "operations");

    if (input.File is not null)
    {
        formData.Add(map, "map");
        formData.Add(new StreamContent(input.File.FileStream), "0", input.File.Name);
    }

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("", formData);

    return response;
}
```

Maybe it is perfectly what you are looking for, but I'm not sure if "MultipartForDataContent" is the equivalent of your need.

Good luck and feel free to ask details :)